# my own .so lib Ubuntu->Debian migration (cannot open shared library)

Tags: ubuntu, g++, debian, shared

Recently i migrated my self from Ubuntu to Debian, (fortunetly didn't delete old OS)
On Ubuntu I had written litle library called

```
libmyh.so
```

I've used it in other app by

```
g++ (...) -lmyh -L../codeSamples/myh/lib
```

and it ran perfectly, but on Debian witch this same makefile i get:

```
./GLUI.out: error while loading shared libraries: libmyh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

any clue wat could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.so` files are not linked by g++, because they are not static libraries (which end with `.a`) or compilation objects (`.o`).

Instead, set the path from where to load dynamic libraries:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/codeSamples/myh/lib
./GLUI.out
```

As this is not related to Debian vs Ubuntu, I think you have set this variable on your Ubuntu system but not on the Debian one.

Comment: yes, it was it, looks like ubuntu has some automated mechanizms to do that, thanks for your help